# Why I am getting this exception when running a JXTA app?

Tags: java, p2p, jxta

I tried running a JXTA app and got the following exceptions..How do I sort this problem?

My codes are::

```
import net.jxta.platform.NetworkManager;


public class Main {

public static void main ( String args [ ] ) {
NetworkManager manager = null ;
try{
manager = new NetworkManager ( NetworkManager . ConfigMode . EDGE , "HelloWorld " ) ;
System . out . println ( " S t a r t ing JXTA" ) ;
manager . startNetwork ( ) ;
System . out . println ( " JXTA St a r t ed " ) ;
} catch ( Exception e ) {
 e . printStackTrace ( ) ;
}
}
}
```

The exception is::

```
Mar 6, 2011 11:26:53 AM net.jxta.platform.NetworkManager configure
INFO: Loading existing configuration. mode = EDGE
Mar 6, 2011 11:26:53 AM net.jxta.platform.NetworkManager startNetwork
INFO: Starting JXTA Network! MODE = EDGE,  HOME = file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/vimal/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorld/.jxta/
Mar 6, 2011 11:26:53 AM net.jxta.impl.loader.RefJxtaLoader findModuleImplAdvertisement
WARNING: Failed to find class for urn:jxta:uuid-DEADBEEFDEAFBABAFEEDBABE0000000C0206
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No matching class for : urn:jxta:uuid-DEADBEEFDEAFBABAFEEDBABE0000000C0206
        at net.jxta.impl.loader.RefJxtaLoader.findClass(RefJxtaLoader.java:240)
        at net.jxta.impl.loader.RefJxtaLoader.findModuleImplAdvertisement(RefJxtaLoader.java:350)
        at net.jxta.impl.peergroup.StdPeerGroup.getDefaultModuleImplAdvertisement(StdPeerGroup.java:353)
        at net.jxta.impl.peergroup.StdPeerGroup.<clinit>(StdPeerGroup.java:143)
        at net.jxta.peergroup.WorldPeerGroupFactory.getDefaultWorldPeerGroupClass(WorldPeerGroupFactory.java:237)
        at net.jxta.peergroup.WorldPeerGroupFactory.<init>(WorldPeerGroupFactory.java:178)
        at net.jxta.peergroup.NetPeerGroupFactory.<init>(NetPeerGroupFactory.java:205)
        at net.jxta.platform.NetworkManager.startNetwork(NetworkManager.java:410)
        at helloworld.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Mar 6, 2011 11:26:53 AM net.jxta.peergroup.WorldPeerGroupFactory newWorldPeerGroup
INFO: Making a new World Peer Group instance using : net.jxta.impl.peergroup.Platform
Mar 6, 2011 11:26:53 AM net.jxta.impl.cm.SrdiIndex clearSrdi
INFO: Clearing SRDI for null
Mar 6, 2011 11:26:53 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Always Access Service (net.jxta.impl.access.always.AlwaysAccessService)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.tcp.IncomingUnicastServer openServerSocket
INFO: Server will accept connections at /0.0.0.0:9701
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the TCP Message Transport (net.jxta.impl.endpoint.tcp.TcpTransport)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the Rendezvous Service (net.jxta.impl.rendezvous.RendezVousServiceImpl)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the Peerinfo Service (net.jxta.impl.peer.PeerInfoServiceImpl)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the Endpoint service (net.jxta.impl.endpoint.EndpointServiceImpl)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the HTTP Message Transport (net.jxta.impl.endpoint.servlethttp.ServletHttpTransport)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : None Membership Service (net.jxta.impl.membership.none.NoneMembershipService)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the Resolver service (net.jxta.impl.resolver.ResolverServiceImpl)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the Discovery service (net.jxta.impl.discovery.DiscoveryServiceImpl)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the IP Multicast Message Transport (net.jxta.impl.endpoint.mcast.McastTransport)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.tcp.TcpTransport startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is an endpoint service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.rendezvous.RendezVousServiceImpl startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is an endpoint service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.peer.PeerInfoServiceImpl startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is a resolver service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.EndpointServiceImpl startApp
INFO: Endpoint Service started.
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.servlethttp.HttpMessageSender start
INFO: HTTP Client Transport started.
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.discovery.DiscoveryServiceImpl startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is a rendezvous service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:45 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.mcast.McastTransport startApp
INFO: IP Multicast Message Transport started.
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.tcp.TcpTransport$MessengerSelectorThread run
INFO: MessengerSelectorThread polling started
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.tcp.TcpTransport startApp
INFO: TCP Message Transport started.
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.tcp.IncomingUnicastServer run
INFO: Server is ready to accept connections
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.rendezvous.adhoc.AdhocPeerRdvService <init>
INFO: RendezVous Service is initialized for urn:jxta:jxta-WorldGroup as an ad hoc peer. 
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.rendezvous.RendezVousServiceImpl startApp
INFO: Rendezvous Serivce started
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.discovery.DiscoveryServiceImpl beEdge
INFO: Switched to a Edge peer role.
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.discovery.DiscoveryServiceImpl startApp
INFO: Discovery service started
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup getInterface
INFO: [urn:jxta:jxta-WorldGroup] GROUP REF COUNT INCREMENTED TO: 1 by
        net.jxta.peergroup.NetPeerGroupFactory.<init>(NetPeerGroupFactory.java:206)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.peergroup.NetPeerGroupFactory newNetPeerGroup
INFO: Instantiating net peer group : urn:jxta:jxta-NetGroup
        Parent : urn:jxta:jxta-WorldGroup "World PeerGroup"[1]
        ID : urn:jxta:jxta-NetGroup
        Name : NetPeerGroup
        impl : null
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup getInterface
INFO: [urn:jxta:jxta-WorldGroup] GROUP REF COUNT INCREMENTED TO: 2 by
        net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup.loadModule(GenericPeerGroup.java:652)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.cm.SrdiIndex clearSrdi
INFO: Clearing SRDI for NetPeerGroup
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the JXME Proxy Service (net.jxta.impl.proxy.ProxyService)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the Relay Message Transport (net.jxta.impl.endpoint.relay.RelayTransport)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : PSE Membership Service (net.jxta.impl.membership.pse.PSEMembershipService)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the Pipe Service (net.jxta.impl.pipe.PipeServiceImpl)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the Router Message Transport (net.jxta.impl.endpoint.router.EndpointRouter)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Always Access Service (net.jxta.impl.access.always.AlwaysAccessService)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the Rendezvous Service (net.jxta.impl.rendezvous.RendezVousServiceImpl)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the Endpoint service (net.jxta.impl.endpoint.EndpointServiceImpl)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the Peerinfo Service (net.jxta.impl.peer.PeerInfoServiceImpl)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the Cryptobased-ID Message Transport (net.jxta.impl.endpoint.cbjx.CbJxTransport)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the Resolver service (net.jxta.impl.resolver.ResolverServiceImpl)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.tls.TlsTransport <init>
INFO: Adjusting TLS connection idle timeout to 300000 millis.
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.tls.TlsTransport <init>
INFO: Adjusting TLS min reconnection idle to 60000 millis.
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.tls.TlsTransport <init>
INFO: Adjusting TLS maximum retry queue age to 120000 millis.
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the TLS Message Transport (net.jxta.impl.endpoint.tls.TlsTransport)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded privileged module : Reference Implementation of the Discovery service (net.jxta.impl.discovery.DiscoveryServiceImpl)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.proxy.ProxyService startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is a endpoint service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.relay.RelayTransport startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is an endpoint service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.membership.pse.PSEMembershipService startApp
INFO: PSE Membmership Service started.
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.pipe.PipeServiceImpl startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is an endpoint service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.router.EndpointRouter startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is an endpoint service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.rendezvous.RendezVousServiceImpl startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is an endpoint service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.EndpointServiceImpl startApp
INFO: Endpoint Service started.
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peer.PeerInfoServiceImpl startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is a resolver service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.cbjx.CbJxTransport startApp
INFO: CbJxTransport started
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.discovery.DiscoveryServiceImpl startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is a rendezvous service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.proxy.ProxyService startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is a discovery service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.relay.RelayTransport startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is a discovery service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.pipe.PipeServiceImpl startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is a rendezvous service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.router.EndpointRouter startApp
WARNING: Endpoint Router start stalled until rendezvous service available
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.rendezvous.edge.EdgePeerRdvService <init>
INFO: RendezVous Service is initialized for urn:jxta:jxta-NetGroup as an Edge peer.
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.rendezvous.RendezVousServiceImpl startApp
INFO: Rendezvous Serivce started
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.discovery.DiscoveryServiceImpl beEdge
INFO: Switched to a Edge peer role.
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.discovery.DiscoveryServiceImpl startApp
INFO: Discovery service started
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.proxy.ProxyService startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is a pipe service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.relay.RelayTransport startApp
WARNING: Stalled until there is a pipe service
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.rendezvous.edge.EdgePeerRdvService$MonitorTask run
WARNING: Rendezvous connection stalled until router is started!
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.cm.SrdiIndex <init>
INFO: [urn:jxta:jxta-NetGroup "NetPeerGroup"[0] / urn:jxta:jxta-WorldGroup "World PeerGroup"[2]] : Initialized pipeResolverSrdi
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.cm.SrdiIndex startGC
INFO: [urn:jxta:jxta-NetGroup "NetPeerGroup"[0] / urn:jxta:jxta-WorldGroup "World PeerGroup"[2]] : Starting SRDI GC Thread for pipeResolverSrdi
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.cm.SrdiIndex <init>
INFO: [urn:jxta:jxta-NetGroup "NetPeerGroup"[0] / urn:jxta:jxta-WorldGroup "World PeerGroup"[2]] : Initialized routerSrdi
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.router.EndpointRouter startApp
INFO: urn:jxta:jxta-NetGroup "NetPeerGroup"[0] / urn:jxta:jxta-WorldGroup "World PeerGroup"[2] : Router Message Transport started.
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.proxy.ProxyService startApp
INFO: JXME Proxy Service started.
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.relay.RelayClient startClient
INFO: Started client : relay://uuid-59616261646162614E5047205032503314CA6F2E29354DA6AE1AAA872F204C3203
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.relay.RelayTransport startApp
INFO: Relay Message Transport started
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.endpoint.relay.RelayClient run
INFO: Start relay client thread
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup loadModule
INFO: Loaded module : Default Network PeerGroup reference implementation (net.jxta.impl.peergroup.ShadowPeerGroup)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup decRefCount
INFO: [urn:jxta:jxta-WorldGroup] GROUP REF COUNT DECCREMENTED TO: 1 by
 JXTA St a r t ed 
        net.jxta.peergroup.NetPeerGroupFactory.<init>(NetPeerGroupFactory.java:220)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup getInterface
INFO: [urn:jxta:jxta-NetGroup] GROUP REF COUNT INCREMENTED TO: 1 by
        net.jxta.platform.NetworkManager.startNetwork(NetworkManager.java:412)
Mar 6, 2011 11:27:46 AM net.jxta.platform.NetworkManager startNetwork
INFO: Started JXTA Network!
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not an error, this is just the default log JXTA.
Try put this line at the beginning of function `main()`:

```
System.setProperty(Logging.JXTA_LOGGING_PROPERTY, Level.OFF.toString());
```